# Parse error: curl in google cloud patflorm

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, parse-platform, ini

I'm trying to use google cloud platform with PHP and with Parse. I followed every step Parse has on its web, but I was unable to make the last step, that is, upload the data to the Parse server.

When I look to the google cloud logs, it says this:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Parse\curl_init() in .../vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php on line 229`

So it seems that curl is not enabled on google cloud platform for my server.

Is there a possibility to overcome this issue?

I looked into `phpinfo();` but there's nothing about curl. For phpinfo() to work I needed to add this line to my php.ini file:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "phpinfo"
```

So I figured this way that the php.ini file works. However, I tried changing the php.ini file again, to add

```
enable_dl = On
extension = php_curl.php
```

but in the phpinfo() the enable_dl stays Off, and also the curl still doesn't work.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: check for curl support = enabled in php info

Comment: There's no curl enabled nor disabled in the php info, and nothing even remotely similar to curl.

Comment: then need to contact host provider or do it self

Comment: the question states that the provider is google app engine, and asks if, and how, is it possible to do it myself.. so yes, I agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl is not (yet) supported on App Engine PHP. You'll need to use urlfetch instead: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/

Comment: I won't rewrite Parse library, but this solves the issue. Thanks for the info.